# How can I put the results of TrigFactor function into a more convenient form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, trigonometry

```
a1 D11 Cos[n x] + a0 a1 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a1 a3 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a2 a4 D11 Cos[n x]
```

I have a large trigonometric expression. Can I factor out different coefficients to `Cos[n x]` and `Sin[n x]` so that it will be easy to copy the expression corresponding to each trigonometric term? I just want the coefficient to each trigonometric function to be printed out separately.

Comment: I have tried to reword your question to make it somewhat more readable. However, I'd appreciate it if you could clarify it further. I am afraid that it is still not very clear what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  it was not written clear by me, sorry for that.  {%[[1, 1]], %[[2, 1]]} this what i was needed as i wanted to print out different coefficients one by one. So now can i use this syntax.

Comment: Amandeep, I noticed that you un-accepted my answer to your question. Does my answer not satisfy your question any more?

Comment: Collect[%, {Cos[n x], Sin[n x]}] this function is not working properly when we have resultant expression in fortran Form e.g xpr = a1* D11* Cos[n* x] + a0* a1 D11 *Cos[n x] + 1/2 a1 *a3 *D11 *Cos[n *x] + 1/2 *a2 *a4 D11* Cos[n x] + a2*a3*a4*Sin[nx] then How we can segregate Cos and Sin terms. And Also we should be able to print out differently one by one so to copy coefficients easily

Comment: Amandeep, is it possible that you have a typo in the last term of the expression in your last comment, i.e. `Sin[nx]` ? Shouldn't that be `Sin[n*x]` or, equivalently, `Sin[n x]` with a space between `n` and `x`? If in fact a space is needed there, then it seems to me that the `Collect` function still works as intended. I will also add another possible way to achieve the same thing using `Coefficient` whose output may be easier to copy out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Second update (2015-05-11):

Amandeep, you recently left a comment with the following expression:

```
xpr = a1*D11*Cos[n*x] + a0*a1*D11*Cos[n*x] + 1/2*a1*a3*D11*Cos[n*x] + 1/2*a2*a4*D11*Cos[n*x] + a2*a3*a4*Sin[n*x]
```

I believe that you may have left out a multiplication sign on the argument of the last `Sin` function. Once we add that back in, the approach using `Collect` still seems to work:

```
Collect[xpr, {Cos[n x], Sin[n x]}]

(* Out: 
(a1 D11 + a0 a1 D11 + (a1 a3 D11)/2 + (a2 a4 D11)/2) Cos[n x] + a2 a3 a4 Sin[n x] 
*)
```

An alternative approach is to use the `Coefficient` function:

```
Coefficient[xpr, Cos[n x]]
Coefficient[xpr, Sin[n x]]

(*Out:
a1 D11 + a0 a1 D11 + (a1 a3 D11)/2 + (a2 a4 D11)/2
a2 a3 a4
*)
```

Hopefully those coefficients should be easy enough to copy and paste, or to otherwise work with programmatically.

### First update

Upon re-reading your question, I realized that the `D11 Cos[n x]` factor is common to all terms in your original expression. It would be just as easy to collect that term:

```
a1 D11 Cos[n x] + a0 a1 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a1 a3 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a2 a4 D11 Cos[n x];
Collect[%, D11 Cos[n x]]

(* Output: (a1 + a0 a1 + (a1 a3)/2 + (a2 a4)/2) D11 Cos[n x] *)
```

---

In my understanding, you want to **factor the expression** to obtain the coefficients of the $\cos(n\ x)$ and $\sin(n\ x)$. However, your example does not contain any `Sin[]` expressions.

Let me consider a modification of your expression instead, in which I have changed some of the original `Cos[n x]` into `Sin[n x]`:

```
a1 D11 Cos[n x] + a0 a1 D11 Sin[n x] + 1/2 a1 a3 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a2 a4 D11 Sin[n x]
```

You can then use `Collect` to obtain your coefficients:

```
Collect[%, {Cos[n x], Sin[n x]}]

(* Output: (a1 D11 + (a1 a3 D11)/2) Cos[n x] + (a0 a1 D11 + (a2 a4 D11)/2) Sin[n x] *)
```

Now they should be easier to copy out.

Alternatively, you could also programmatically extract the two coefficient from the result above, as parts of the output expression:

```
{%[[1, 1]], %[[2, 1]]}

(* Output: {a1 D11 + (a1 a3 D11)/2, a0 a1 D11 + (a2 a4 D11)/2} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Simplify`

```
expr = a1 D11 Cos[n x] + a0 a1 D11 Cos[n x] + 1/2 a1 a3 D11 Cos[n x] + 
   1/2 a2 a4 D11 Cos[n x];

expr // Simplify
```

> 1/2 (a1 (2 + 2 a0 + a3) + a2 a4) D11 Cos[n x]

```
expr2 = a1*D11*Cos[n*x] + a0*a1 D11*Cos[n*x] + 
   1/2 a1*a3*D11*Cos[n*x] + 1/2*a2*a4 D11*Cos[n*x] + a2*a3*a4*Sin[n*x];

expr2 // Simplify
```

> 1/2 (a1 (2 + 2 a0 + a3) + a2 a4) D11 Cos[n x] + a2 a3 a4 Sin[n x]

Comment: I can do above thing, but I want different expression factors to be printed out differently

Comment: Collect[%, {Cos[n x], Sin[n x]}]   this function is not working properly when we have resultant expression in fortran Form e.g xpr = a1* D11* Cos[n* x] + a0* a1 *D11 *Cos[n* x] + 1/2 *a1 *a3 *D11 *Cos[n *x] + 
   1/2 *a2 *a4* D11* Cos[n *x] + a2*a3*a4*Sin[n*x]   then How we can segregate Cos and Sin terms. And Also we should be able to print out differently one by one so to copy coefficients easily.

Comment: @Amandeep - I have added the expression from your comment. If the output from the use of `Simplify` is not the result that you want, you need to clarify want you want by providing an explicit example of the desired output.